# How to return specific properties of a custom vb.net object

Tags: vb.net, system.reflection

I'm trying to generate a list of all of the `TableName` and `FieldName` properties for a custom object type called `LxTextBox`. I've gotten as far as generating a list of all of the `LxTextBox` names on my form, but I can't figure out a way to call the properties of the custom object... I've been looking into System.Reflection, but I haven't ever used it. Additionally, I'm returning the list to a `RichTextBox` while I'm testing this out, but ultimately, I need to return each objects properties as a data row. Example:

```
    ObjectName      Table           Field
    ---------------------------------------
    LxTextBox23     SomeTbl         SomeFld
```

Here's my code to return the list - updated based on @OneFineDay...

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Application.UDF.Controls

Public Class MeasurementsControl

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim textBoxList As New List(Of Control)
        Dim customTbs = GetAllControls(Me)

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        For index As Integer = 0 To customTbs.Count - 1
            sb.Append(customTbs.Item(index).TableName & "." & customTbs.Item(Index).FieldName & System.Environment.NewLine)
        Next

        RichTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString

    End Sub

    Private Function GetAllControls(ByVal searchWithin As Control) As List(Of LxTextbox)
        Dim returnList As List(Of LxTextbox) = Nothing
        If searchWithin.HasChildren Then
            returnList = searchWithin.Controls.OfType(Of LxTextbox).ToList
            For Each ctrl As Control In searchWithin.Controls
                returnList.AddRange(GetAllControls(ctrl))
            Next
        End If
        Return returnList
    End Function
End Class
```

I made the changes suggested and I'm throwing an error: `OfType` is not a member of `System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection`

FYI - Adding `Imports System.Linq` did not fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are boxing it into a `Control` the object from where it derives, where you're custom properties cannot be found. You can cast it right from the control collection.

```
Dim customTbs = GetAllControls(Me)

'recursive function
Private Function GetAllControls(ByVal searchWithin As Control) As List(Of LxTextbox)
 Dim returnList As List(Of LxTextbox) = Nothing
 returnList = searchWithin.Controls.OfType(Of LxTextbox).ToList
 If searchWithin.HasChildren Then
  For Each ctrl As Control In searchWithin.Controls
    Dim ctrls = GetAllControls(ctrl)
    If Not ctrls Is Nothing Then returnList.AddRange(ctrls)
  Next
 End If
 Return returnList
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to vb.net... I'm a little unsure of how to use what you suggested? In other words, how do I modify what I already have to use this?

Comment: @OneFineDay - Updated my question based on your suggestion.